Nginx rate limiting doesn't seem to work at all
I am trying to make rate limiting work for PHP files (which we don't use at all, and I don't want hackers to endlessly try a million PHP files on our server). We're using CloudFlare to proxy our site, so I included realip config to get access to the real IP address.
This is my config:
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
http {
        # ...

        # Define CloudFlare IP ranges
        set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
        set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
        set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
        set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
        set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
        set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
        set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
        set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
        set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
        set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
        set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;

        # Use the header sent by CloudFlare to extract the real client IP
        real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

        # Create rate limiting zone
        limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=deny_rules:10m rate=1r/m;

        # ...
}

/etc/nginx/deny_rules.conf
location ~ \.php$ {
        limit_req zone=deny_rules nodelay;
        return 404;
}

And finally my site config:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com
server {
        server_name www.example.com;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        charset utf-8;
        charset_types *;
        resolver 9.9.9.9;
        include /etc/nginx/deny_rules.conf;
    
        # ...
}

In the access log I am seeing the real IP addresses show up instead of CloudFlare, so the realip module is doing its thing correctly. But no matter how often or how quick I access www.example.com/whatever.php, I always get a 404. I would expect to get a 503 from the second request on. What am I doing wrong? It's like the return 404; is overwriting the status code from the rate limiter, something like that?
We're using Nginx 1.18.0 on Debian 11.

return is executed earlier than limit_req so latter is actually never executed. If you want to check limit_req, use something else. Actual file, or echo module.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases

Thanks. Replacing it with deny all seems to solve the problem.
